# Can I customize a keyboard shortcut to exit a zoom meeting?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, zoom

I went into the zoom settings but there didn't seem to be an editable keyboard shortcut to leave a meeting easily. It looks like command-w will close the window, and I'm trying to find a way to customize a setting so that all I need to hit is "delete" (not backspace) on my external keyboard to activate that same command-w function.

I changed mute/unmute and video on/off to my never used page up/down keys and got really excited about the opportunity to optimize my zoom life.

Would appreciate any suggestions offered in a computer-dumdum-friendly way! Thanks so much.

Comment: This really isn’t advisable because a multi-key shortcut gives a degree of “safety” from closing windows unintentionally.  Once you’ve mastered the key combo systemwide, you won’t need single key custom shortcuts.

Comment: I added another answer to the dupe on using single-key shortcuts - however, this won't let you use Del.

Comment: Thank you! My keyboard has both backspace as well as delete, so I don’t mind losing del for this purpose, but it looks like what I want may not be possible.